# How to write an SQL query for this use case?

Tags: sql

Suppose I've got a table with three fields: `event_name`, `event_timestamp` `event_result`. Each row is an occurrence of an *event* `event_name` occurred at `event_timestamp` with some `event_result`. For example:

```
 event_name | event_timestamp  | event_result
 -------------------------------------------
 event_a    | 2018-04-29 00:00 | result_x1
 event_a    | 2018-04-29 00:00 | result_x2
 event_b    | 2018-04-29 00:00 | result_x1
 event_a    | 2018-04-29 00:00 | result_x3
 event_b    | 2018-04-29 00:00 | result_x3
```

Now I need a SQL query to select rows with the *latest* `event_timestamp` for *every* `event_name` within given range of `event_timestamp`.

How would you write such a query ? I guess it should be standard SQL that works with any reasonable SQL database.

Comment: Could you provide your expect result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `subquery` :

```
select * 
from table t
where event_timestamp = (select max(event_timestamp) 
                         from table 
                         where event_name = t.event_name);
```

And, in general the most effective method is to use *ranking* functions (if support)

```
select * from (
      select *,
             row_number() over (partition by event_name order by event_timestamp desc) Seq 
      from table t
      where  event_timestamp between @start and @end
) t
where Seq = 1;
```

Comment: I tend to prefer `(DENSE_)RANK` for these situations. When rows are tied, as is the case in op's sample data, I usually want to know about it, rather than having a random row returned. In my experience, unexpected ties are an indication of bad data.

Answer (score 1):

The most portable solution would probably be something like:

```
SELECT    E.*
FROM      Event E
INNER JOIN (
             SELECT  event_name 
             ,       MAX(event_timestamp) MAX_DT
             FROM    Event 
             WHERE   event_timestamp <= @SomeDate
                  AND event_timestamp > @SomeOtherDate
             GROUP BY event_name 
           ) MAXED
        ON MAXED.event_name = E.event_name 
        AND MAXED.MAX_DT = E.event_timestamp
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
SELECT event_name
    ,MAX(event_timestamp)
FROM myTable
WHERE event_timestamp BETWEEN date1
        AND date2
GROUP BY event_name
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use group by and include the max event_timestamp
In MSSQL:

```
select
event_name
, MAX(event_timestamp)
from [table_name]
where event_timestamp between '2018-04-20' and '2018-04-30'
group by event_name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `your_table` 
WHERE `event_timestamp` BETWEEN 'your_start_range'AND 'your_end_range'
GROUP BY `event_name`
ORDER BY `event_timestamp` DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

this code work for ms sql

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT
        *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY event_name ORDER BY event_timestamp DESC) AS row_no
     FROM    Event 
     WHERE
        event_timestamp BETWEEN @BeginDate AND @EndDate) as tbl
WHERE row_no = 1
```